# a simple problem with ForLoop in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

I want it to run three times but it actually never runs the loop and gets out.
In VB 6.0 I could do that with a similar structure but how can I achieve the same thing with C# for loop? I want to to count down but it is not ALWAYS the case, sometimes I am passing "1" and sometimes "-1" for the step , when passed with "-1" it does not work

```
    for (int L = 3; L <= 1; L += -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dfsdff");
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes because you have the second clause (the "keep going whilst this is true" clause) the wrong way around, try this:

```
 for (int L = 3; L >= 1; L--)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dfsdff");
    }
```

Now it says "start at 3", "decrement" (--) whilst L is bigger than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your terminal condition of `L <= 1` is what is throwing you off.

You probably meant to reverse that and say `L >= 1`. Otherwise when L is initialized to 3, and then the terminal is evaluated it would immediately return false saying that L is greater than 1, and therefore terminate your loop.

Answer (score 3):

the for loop can be written out as:

```
for(variable L = 3; as long as L satisfies condition L <= 1; increment L by -1)
```

Your L will always be greater than 1, so the loop never gets executed. The right way would be either:

```
for(int L = 0; L <= 2; L++)
```

or

```
for(int L = 2; L >= 0; L--)
```

if you want to start with 1, just modify accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
for (int L = 3; L >= 1; L--)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dfsdff");
    }
```

That should count down for you, I've corrected it.  They are correct, it was an infinite loop.  Here is another way to do it, that might make more brain sense.

```
int L = 3
while( L > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your clever message);
    L--;
}
```

Comment: That would countdown alright. Countdown for a very long time.

Comment: I don't think it will. Only once. L will be decremented to equal 2. Which then fails the test clause (which is never true).

Comment: @winwaed, the author had previously written the terminal condition as `L <= 3`, which would have resulted in it looping for a very long time.

Comment: Ah okay - so it looks like he had 3 versions and I caught the correction to the version you commented on! :-)